# Android Studio - APK not working on my device

Tags: java, android-studio

Its my first time using android studio, once i build the APK and upload it to my server and download it on my mobile and attempt to run it i get a error saying 'App not Installed', never had this before

I've not found any solutions

https://github.com/Aaron-Akhtar/Calculator-Android/blob/master/src/main/java/club/shprqness/calculator/MainActivity.java

I expected it to open as any normal apk and run the way i wanted it too.

Comment: Try building a signed APK and run on your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your APK,Or remove previously installed apps.

Build -->Generate signed bundle apk --> apk  --> creat your sign